# Where can I get Professional Crystal Reports developer support?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have been struggling for days with a crystal report now. No one can answer my query on stack overflow so is there anywhere I can get some developer support for crystal.

Ideally I want a business objects developer to connect to my machine, look at my code and tell me why the database name refuses to change in any of the examples crystal have provided.

If anyone knows of anyone offering this kind of service, or has some working code to change the database of a crystal report at runtime.

I have asked the question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723903/crystal-report-pain-cant-seem-to-change-database

Why is something that should be so simple such a waste of time!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Part of the problem with your other question is that you didn't include the "Crystal-reports" tag, just the "Crystal-reports 2008" tag.  The former is more common and gives you a much wider audience.  Fixed.
2. This doesn't happen too often, but your other question is actually giving users a case of "information overload".  I did a print preview and it came out to 7 pages.  Can you cut back on some of the code? (Yes, you might accidently omit the real source of the problem, but that's just life)
3. Paid consultants may be more dedicated to finding the answer, but he/she isn't necessarily smarter. Try the official support page @ http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/boc/support. If you purchase a "maintenance agreement" with SAP, you'll get exactly the professional support you're looking for.
4. (After all this talking, I'd like to just answer your question and be done with it, but I don't know ASP.)

Comment: Thanks PowerUser, I didnt think of tagging both crystal-reports and 2008 (thanks for doing it for me). Just had a look at the code to see if there is anything I can remove, there are a few methods that are not required to recreate the user control. I have been on the SAP website, I find it hard to find anything useful on there! Ill start by tidying up the code and then consider placing a bounty. +1 for the help, ill leave this question open for a while to see what else trickles in :)

Comment: Much like their main software product, the SAP website is unnecessarily complex, but functional :) You might find something in their forums.

Comment: I forgot all about the bounty system.  Good idea, that could work too!

Answer (score 1):

You could also try [BOB](http://www.forumtopics.com/busobj/index.php).

Comment: Thanks, I had not found that before.. :)

Comment: Forgot to mention that you could hire me.  I'm a professional CR designer/developer.  ;)